RabbitMQ set the LivenessProbe exec command using terraform helm_release provider
I am trying to overwrite de default livenessProbe and readinessProbe execution command using the terraform helm_release provider.
Unfortunatly after many attempts, it looks like the command is not overwritten after deployment and keeps the default values.
I use Azure Kubernetes.  I have tried to delete the statefull set, deployed resources and also the helm release using lens but that did not do the trick.  I have also tried to add the livenessProbe.exec.command in the values block but that did not work either.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  I do not want to use an external values file.
Here is my code :
resource "helm_release" "rabbitmq" {
  repository = var.repository
  description = var.description
  lint = var.lint
  verify = var.verify
  name = var.name
  version = var.version
  chart = var.chart
  namespace = var.namespace
  create_namespace = var.create_namespace
  
  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = var.service_type
  }

  set {
    name  = "livenessProbe.exec.command"
    value = "rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping"
  }

  values = [
    <<EOF
service:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "my-subnet"
EOF
  ]
}

Thank you !

Which chart are you using?

I use the bitnami chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/rabbitmq

I think you need to see how to configure customLivenessProbe: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/rabbitmq/values.yaml#L851.

After many attempts, I made it work using the customLivenessProbe parameter and specifying it in the values block like below.
I tried it before and it failed but I think that was due to a misconfiguration in the customReadinessProbe block.
Thanks to Marko E for the tip !
resource "helm_release" "rabbitmq" {

  repository = var.repository
  description = var.description
  lint = var.lint
  verify = var.verify
  name = var.name
  version = var.version
  chart = var.chart
  namespace = var.namespace
  create_namespace = var.create_namespace
   
  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = var.service_type
  }

  values = [
    <<EOF
service:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "my-subnet"
customLivenessProbe: 
  exec:
    command:
      - bin/sh
      - '-ec'
      - rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  timeoutSeconds: 20
  periodSeconds: 30
  successThreshold: 1
  failureThreshold: 6
EOF
  ]
}

